# Python TelegramBot функции

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot

Подскажите почему не отрабатывает 3 функция?Если убираю вторую то работает.Я наверно неправильно понимаю как работают функции в пайтон...Скиньте плс ссылку на хорошие доки)

```
import telebot

bot = telebot.TeleBot('ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ')

keyboard1 = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
keyboard1.row('Купить','Пожаловаться','Обменять','Нужна помощь')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Привет, ты написал мне /start', reply_markup=keyboard1)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text(message):
    greeting = ['привет' , "hi" , "hello" , "здрасте" , "здравствуйте"]
    if message.text.lower() in greeting:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text,reply_markup=keyboard1)
    elif message.text.lower() == 'пока':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Прощай, создатель')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def send_text1(message):
    greeting1 = ['пожаловаться','обменять']
    if message.text.lower() in greeting1:
        bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAADAgADpAEAAo5EEQItOULSZGLxYxYE')
    elif message.text.lower() == 'пока':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Прощай, создатель')


bot.polling()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Доки](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI)

Второй декоратор обрабатывает все сообщения типа text, соответственно третьему декоратору ничего не остается и он игнорируется.
Ваша логика должна разделяться внутри одного декоратора:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
        def send_text(message):
            greeting = ['привет' , "hi" , "hello" , "здрасте" , "здравствуйте"]
            greeting1 = ['пожаловаться','обменять']
            if message.text.lower() in greeting:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text,reply_markup=keyboard1)      
            elif message.text.lower() in greeting1:
                bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, 'CAADAgADpAEAAo5EEQItOULSZGLxYxYE')
            elif message.text.lower() == 'пока':
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Прощай, создатель')
```